# Not able to start Genymotion VD -- player.exe has stopped working

Tags: android

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: player.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    55a929e1
  Fault Module Name:    ig4icd32.dll
  Fault Module Version: 8.15.10.1986
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4aeb3266
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000328e0
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.2
  Locale ID:    16393
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Some other info

Android Studio - 1.2

Oracle VM 4.3.12

Genymotion 2.5.2

Genymotion VD - Google Nexus4 -4.11 - API16 - 768*1280

I tried some solutions given in SO but my problem seems different.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my graphic driver's issue. After searching in google for some time I saw few solutions of updating Graphic Driver.

I am using Dell Inspiron 1564 Laptop with Intel's graphic driver.

Updated the same from-

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-1564/drivers

Or if you are using different model of machine of Dell, please search for "View a different product" or directly click at "View a different product" link.

To get latest driver,

1. Please select "Video" in "Refine your results​:" filter or directly 
   jump to "Video" option(The last option).
2. Select the first "R271008.exe", download it, run it and restart your    machine.

I hope this will work for you.

Thanks

Jaikrat